# How can I take data's from two's input="text" and textarea then show them inside <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Sorry, all
My education in JQuery total around 1,5 week. I'm newbie. mostly studying HTLM/CSS. But I faced with a problem with JSQuery. For me need to somehow add data's from right side to left side (more details in code)

ps: reading info already 4days but absolutely my brain dead, cant understand syntax. PLease, at least which syntax I should use
I know there should be ".val()"

```js
console.log('#button');
console.log('#title-box');
console.log('#describe-box');
var title = $('#title-box');
var describe = $('#describe-box');

$(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('ul').append("<li><h3> + $('#title-box') + <span>&#10060;</span></h3></li>");
        console.log($('title').val());
        console.log($('describe').val());
    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 900px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

textarea {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    outline: none;
}

span {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 9px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    display: inline;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    height: 105px;
    width: 470px;
    padding: 14px 0 16px 0;
    margin: 26px 0 22px 0;
    background-color: white;
}

.li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.clearfix::after { 
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

.wrapper {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    height: 768px;
    width: 1000px;
}
    
.left-item {
    font-size: 13px;
}

.left-container{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}


.right-item {
    font-size: 13px;
}

.right-container{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

    .right-form{
        width: 430px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        margin-top: 26px;
        padding: 1px 0 14px 40px;
    }

.title{
    margin: 29px 0 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #adb4c5;
}

.describe{
    margin: 29px 0 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #adb4c5;
}

#title-box{
    padding: 0px 5px;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#button {
    background-color: #2174fd;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 18px 56px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 22px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <title>To DO list</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="left-container clearfix">
            <div class="left-item">
                <h2>left side:</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="list-container">
                <ul>
                    
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>
            <div class="right-container clearfix">
                <div class="right-item">
                    <h2>right-side</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="right-form">
                    <p class="title">* title</p>
                    <input id="title-box" type="text" value="" size="21">
                    <p class="describe">* describe</p>
                    <textarea id="describe-box" name="describe" rows="15" cols="46" value=""></textarea>
                    <button id="button">add</button>
                </div>  
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `        $('ul').append("<li><h3> + $('#title-box') + <span>&#10060;</span></h3></li>");`
you should use template strings or get the value of it and not write it literally inside the string
`"<li><h3>" + $('#title-box').val() + "<span>&#10060;</span></h3></li>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that here no concatenation will happen because you don't close the first part of the string. The $('#title-box') will put literal in the string

```
$('ul').append("<li><h3> + $('#title-box') + <span>&#10060;</span></h3></li>");
```

You need to concat the value by closing the string before the value and behind it.

```
$('ul').append('<li><h3>' + $('#title-box').val() + '<span>&#10060;</span></h3></li>');
```

```js
var title = $('#title-box');
var describe = $('#describe-box');

$(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('ul').append('<li><h3>' + $('#title-box').val() + '<span>&#10060;</span></h3></li>');
        console.log($('title').val());
        console.log($('describe').val());
    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 900px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

textarea {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    outline: none;
}

span {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 9px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    display: inline;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    height: 105px;
    width: 470px;
    padding: 14px 0 16px 0;
    margin: 26px 0 22px 0;
    background-color: white;
}

.li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.clearfix::after { 
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

.wrapper {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    height: 768px;
    width: 1000px;
}
    
.left-item {
    font-size: 13px;
}

.left-container{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}


.right-item {
    font-size: 13px;
}

.right-container{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

    .right-form{
        width: 430px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        margin-top: 26px;
        padding: 1px 0 14px 40px;
    }

.title{
    margin: 29px 0 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #adb4c5;
}

.describe{
    margin: 29px 0 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #adb4c5;
}

#title-box{
    padding: 0px 5px;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#button {
    background-color: #2174fd;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 18px 56px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 22px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <title>To DO list</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="left-container clearfix">
            <div class="left-item">
                <h2>left side:</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="list-container">
                <ul>
                    
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>
            <div class="right-container clearfix">
                <div class="right-item">
                    <h2>right-side</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="right-form">
                    <p class="title">* title</p>
                    <input id="title-box" type="text" value="" size="21">
                    <p class="describe">* describe</p>
                    <textarea id="describe-box" name="describe" rows="15" cols="46" value=""></textarea>
                    <button id="button">add</button>
                </div>  
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```